# ffmpeg automaticall re-scaling. How can I prevent it wihtout having to provide height for 'force_original_aspect_ratio'?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to take screenshots of a video file. It seems some video files end up looking squished because ffmpeg is automatically rescaling them for some reason. I am using a python package to do this, not the CLI tool. The only options I am using are specifying the timestamp to capture and quiet output. I am try to get a lossless shot. I don't know why it is resizing automatically. I tried using the `force_original_aspect_ratio` option and setting it to `-1` but it does not work without specifying the height. Is there any way to prevent this from happening without needing to provide the height? I can do that for my script but it seems unnecessary. It should just keep it as-is.

EDIT:
BTW, the video is 720x480. Oddly, the metadata on the video and the screen shot are both 720x480. However I lined them up and the video is clearly wider. VLC takes a screenshot just fine. Someone told me ffmpeg just has issues with SD files. I don't know.

Comment: What are the scale filter arguments?

Comment: There aren't any. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: Your Q says, "tried using the force_original_aspect_ratio option and setting it to -1". That option is a scale filter option. How did you set it? Show your code.

Comment: Well, it's squishing it automatically, with no scale options set. As you said, I tried `force_original_aspect_ratio=-1` but that only works when specifying the height, which I don't want to do. So the issue isn't that my filter argument is wrong, it's that it's changing the size with no filter set. I did a little more looking. ffmpeg says the video is 720x480. The screenshot is also 720x480, which makes no sense because they are obviously different. VLC also says the video is 720x480. But if I take a screenshot with VLC, it looks correct, however the resulting image is 853x480.

Comment: Maybe either VLC and ffmpeg are reporting the size wrong or they are correct, the images are squished originally, but the players automatically correct the aspect ratio on playback?

Comment: Add scale filter with w: `iw*sar` and h: ih.

Comment: @Gyan, thanks, that seems to have worked. But the image size of the screen shot it 853x480, like it was for VLC. I'm glad it's working now but I'd like to get an understanding of what exactly is going on though. What is it about this particular file?

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/26041